# Не изменяется цвет ссылки при наводке хотя так работает с почтой

Tags: html, css

Я использую шаблон сайта и хотел бы спросить где параметр находится который изменяет цвет ссылки при наводке. Я уже пробовал менять параметры в css `a{}` ну там другое смотрите:

Это без наводки картинка

[image: Без]

Это я навел на ссылку с почтой `<a>href="mailto:google@mail.ru">ПОЧТА</a>`
[image: почта]

Видите она стала белой

.

Это я навел на ссылку

[image: ссылка]

Она не становится белой

Кстати если ввести неправильную ссылку ну например `<a href="google.com">Нерабочая ссылка (тк нет https)<a/>` то при наводке этот текст тоже белеет. Значит в шаблоне сайта какой то параметр есть который именно за ссылки рабочие отвечает. Помогите

Comment: Если это правда ваш код, то там `=` пропущено

Comment: Я на сайте писал, ошибся

Comment: откройте браузер, найдите вашу сылку в инспекторе, и продеморнстрируйте его `html` и `css` код (можно скрином )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

За это отвечает псевдокласс hover. А уж где там у вас в стилях у вас написано - это мы не узнаем. Экстрасенсы в отпуске, как говорится.

Если используете google chrome,  то нажмите f12, найдите свою ссылку и добавьте ей hover. А потом посмотрите откуда берется ваш цвет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.link-1, .link-2 {
    color: blue
}

.link-1:hover {
    color: black;
}

.link-2:hover {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link-1">Ссылка, которая меняет цвет</a><br>
<a href="#" class="link-2">Ссылка, которая не меняет цвет</a>
```

Comment: .whitelink:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF; /* Цвет ссылки */ 
   }

Comment: И не меняет цвет почему-то

Comment: @JoyZZZZZZZ значит цвет при наведении определяется в другом месте и это правило имеет больший приоритет. Как я уже написал, вы можете это узнать, открыв инструменты разработчика (f12). Найдите свою ссылку в коде, добавьте ей псевдокласс hover, нажав на галочку как на изображении. И потом посмотрите из какого css свойства берется берется текущий цвет. Но если это слишком сложно, то напишите в css вот так `.whitelink:hover { color: #FFFFFF!important; }`

Comment: А что в этом способе плохого? Спасибо, импортант помог

Comment: @JoyZZZZZZZ ну те стили, которые вы переопределили таким способом для чего-то в шаблоне были написаны. Есть вероятность, что вы изменили цвет ссылок не только там, где вы хотели это сделать, но и там, где это было не нужно.